# Highlight cell after modalview has been dissmissed

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a table view and a toolbar where items can be added to the table view. The addItemView is presented modally.

Now, when i dismiss the modal view i would like to indicate which cell was added. For now i have used the setSelected and deselct methods on UITableView, but they are fired too quickly. What would be a good approach to give the user a good indication on which cell was added?

Could i add a timer which prevented the setSelected method from firing right away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i should have tried that first...
I just added:
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.4 target:self selector:@selector(highlightAddedRow:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

and the highlightAddedRow method accesses a property which indicates which rowIndex was added.